# Why python3.8 cannot import but python3.5 can?

Tags: python, pip, python-import, python-3.5, python-3.8

I have installed python3.5 and python3.8 in my Ubuntu 16.04

When I execute **python3.5** in shell I can do

```
>>> import gi
```

And it works perfectly, but, if I try it in the **python3.8** shell I get following

```
>>> import gi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most
likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Why there is such a different behavior between my versions? How can I solve it?
(Thanks! :))

**Note:** This question is a small part of my big problem. When I try to execute python applications that call the package `gi` with `#!/usr/bin/python3.8`, I get the same problem, but the applications run smooth with `#!/usr/bin/python3.5`

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this issue for me is doing the command: 
`sudo -H pip3.8 install gobject PyGObject`
and after words I closed down the IDE and then reopened it. It then worked for me.

Comment: Your suggestion `sudo -H pip3.8 install gobject PyGObject` outputs `sudo -H pip3.8 install gobject PyGObject`. When I enter `sudo -H python3.8 -m pip install gobject PyGObject` I get `/usr/bin/python3.8: No module named pip`. :-\

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus doesn't that mean all you have to do is install pip?

Comment: @SRColledge `pip` installation was not the problem: I had `pip` installed in python 3.8. At the end I gave up in this issue, but I am thankful for your help, anyway. In April I had to change from Xubuntu 16.04. to 18.04., because the 16.04. version is no more supported. So I have this problem no more. I hope, this thread can help someone, though.

Comment: It didn't work for me either as I'm using python 3.10